# casting a node to integer

Tags: c++, c, casting

The code gives an **error** saying that "**no operator matches these two operands**" in the `if` comparison statement. I interpret,it should mean that "a node can't be converted/casted into an integer". But, the print statement prints an integer value for `w[2]` when used with `%d` format. Why is that happening? Isn't `printf` casting it?

```
NODE *w=(NODE *)malloc(4*sizeof(NODE)); 
if(w[2]==0)
  printf("%d\n",w[2]);
```

The structure of the node is-

```
struct node{
  int key;
  struct node *father;
  struct node *child[S];
  int *ss;
  int current;
};
```

---

Please refer to the comments of cdhowie . He has answered the question.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: What do you think `w[2] == 0` should do?  Compare every field in the (third) node to see if it is zero?  What if there is a float?  What if there is a pointer?

Comment: @wallyk but  then why is it printing a integer value in printf?

Comment: see Mystical's comment: turn compiler warnings up to highest value

Comment: probably because you told it to expect one. read through the printf source and see if offers any clues.

Comment: Using `printf()` on a value that is an object reference or temporary is undefined behavior, IIRC.  The number that is being displayed is likely a matter of implementation, and cannot be relied upon across compilers or platforms.  What you are seeing is similar (if not equal) to the output of `std::cout << *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(w[2]));`.

Comment: @cdhowie printf() is printing but compairson gives error. Why is that?

Comment: @user1708762 Because `printf()` accepts input of close to *any* type.  However, the output will only make sense if the input matches the format specifiers you have indicated.  In this case you are asking it to display an object as a number.  It tries, but the value it displays may not be the same on a different compiler or platform.  This is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing with respect to `printf()` is undefined.  `printf()` does not type-check arguments; it assumes that the arguments you've given match the format specifiers you have given in the string argument.

In other words, you are invoking *undefined behavior*.  The type code `%d` expects an `int` as an argument, but you are specifying a `NODE` object instead.  Anything at all might happen here -- your program might crash, for example (though this is unlikely).  At the very least, you cannot rely on this particular output to be consistent across platforms or compilers.

If you turn your compiler warnings up to the maximum, it should warn you about this.  Modern compilers will type-check arguments to `printf()` for you (assuming that you provide a string literal as the first argument, and not a variable or expression), but this is purely a compile-time check and it will only generate warnings, not errors.